# Check if one list contains any elements from another

Tags: c#, linq

I am just trying to return true if one list contains any of the Name/Value from list2:

This would be my structure:

```
public class TStockFilterAttributes
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}

List<TStockFilterAttributes> List1 = new List<TStockFilterAttributes>();
List<TStockFilterAttributes> List2 = new List<TStockFilterAttributes>();
```

This should return true:

```
List1.Add(new TStockFilterAttributes { Name = "Foo", Value = "Bar" });
List2.Add(new TStockFilterAttributes { Name = "Foo", Value = "Bar" });
```

But this would return false because Name && Value don't match:

```
List1.Add(new TStockFilterAttributes { Name = "Foo", Value = "Bar" });
List2.Add(new TStockFilterAttributes { Name = "Foo", Value = "Foo" });
```

Each list could contains lots of different values and I just need to know if any one of List1 matches any one in List2.

I have tried using:

```
return List1.Intersect(List2).Any();
```

but this seems to return false in all cases, I am assuming this is because I am holding a class in List rather than a simple int / string?

Comment: `Intersect` works on references by default, since you create a new object every time, you'd have to write your own [`IEqualityComparer<TStockFilterAttributes>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementation for your class:

```
public class TStockFilterAttributes
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        TStockFilterAttributes other = obj as TStockFilterAttributes;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        return Name == obj.Name && Value == obj.Value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode() ^ Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Or provide a comparer to `Intersect` function.

Comment: I tried this just after posting the question here and it worked. I will mark this as the answer when I am allowed as it's the same as my solution. Thanks.

Comment: @webnoob you are welcome. The is issue was in default `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations, which use object references to compare different objects. And Linq use these methods for comparison.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming performance doesn't matter:

```
List1.Any(l1 => List2.Any(l2 => l1.Key == l2.Key && l1.Value == l2.Value));
```

Alternatives would be to override Equals or to make it a Struct (probably not appropriate)

Answer (score 3):

```
var query = List1.Where(x => List2.Exists(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.Value == x.Value));
```

But performance might be bad

Answer (score 1):

The trouble here is that you are comparing references and not the objects.  Since you create a new object each time, the Lists will never hold the same references.

Try:

```
var FooBar = new TStockFilterAttributes { Name = "Foo", Value = "Bar" };
var FooFoo = new TStockFilterAttributes { Name = "Foo", Value = "Foo" };
List1.Add(FooBar);
List2.Add(FooBar);
List2.Add(FooFoo);
return List1.Intersect(List2);
```

Comment: That is what I thought the problem was, I have now implemented an IEqualityComparer to sort the issue.

Comment: Absolutely.  You have two approaches here depending on what you need.  More often than not, we want to check references but sometimes you only need to compare the values.

Answer (score 0):

late to bump in but with intersect we can use select and avoid using equality.

```
list1.Select(Function(p) p.ItemID).Intersect(list2.Select(Function(p)p.ItemID)).Any()
```